# How can I get MongoDB working with php 5.3.5 & wamp?

Tags: php, apache, mongodb, wamp

I keep receiving this error (from the apache log) and I cannot get the php_mongo.dll module loaded with the 32bit versions of both mongo and wamp.

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.5/ext/php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
in <b>Unknown</b> on line <b>0</b><br />
```

Whats most frustrating is the fact that I can see the file sitting in the exact directory the error message is telling me it can't find it! I've rechecked the php.ini edits were correct, but I still can't get the module to load when php starts up. Any ideas what the '\r\n in Unknown on line 0' may correspond to?

php 5.3.5
apache 2.2.17 
windows 7

Thanks!

Comment: Call PHP from the command-line while you have ensured that the module is marked to be loaded from CLI as well. You should get a message box with more information why the library can not be loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've just removed wamp and installed / configured apache 2.2 and php 5.3 manually without mysql to see if it was a problem with wamp. I'm still getting the same error - even the message box that pops up when loading the CLI displays the same information pasted up there. "PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'g:/php/ext/php_mongo.dll' - The specified module could not be found."

Comment: have you followed all instructions listed on this page: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Quickstart+Windows

Comment: What are the permissions on `c:/wamp/bin/php...php_mongo.dll`? Can you access that file from your command line? Can you access that file from PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you use the thread safe version of the mongodb extension plugin. I stumbled upon the exact same errors while using the non-thread-safe versions.

To download the right extension, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.windows

Most likely you'll need the VC9 (Thread Safe) version.

Comment: +1 to this. Get the driver from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/downloads, and install the one that is in the folder ending with "ts" (for Thread Safe).

Comment: Just to bring some updated info to the answer above : upon downloading the latest package, I ended up with 4 files, whose names respectively ended with vc9, vc9-nts, vc9-x86_64 and vc9-nts-x86_64. The first two weren't considered as "valid Win32 applications" by Windows, and the last one caused WAMP to fail loading php5.dll AND the Mongo extension DLL itself. Using the third worked just fine. I'm on Windows 7 64 bits. Kinda suspect "nts" to mean "Not Thread Safe", but that's just silly, right ?

Answer (score 1):

php_mongo-1.4.3-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll worked for me on wamp 2.2, PHP 5.3.8, Windows 7 64bit

These newer versions

php_mongo-1.4.3-5.5-vc11-x86_64.dll

php_mongo-1.4.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll

didn't work for me. 
They gave the same error: 'Unable to load dynamic library - The specified procedure could not be found'.

Also - make sure the MongoDB database process is running per this webpage:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

Answer (score 1):

I got same error in xampp. I have tried with older version of thread safe mongodb and it worked.